# Change color of results of a javascript change function

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function, the only thing I can't figure out how to do is set the M to bold red and the L to black within the input text based on it being an M or L.  How do I colorize the result within the input? Here is the complete code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>
   <tr>  
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="Shared" id="Shared" value="YES" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="One" id="One" value="YES" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="Two" id="Two" value="YES" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="Three" id="Three" value="YES" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="Four" id="Four" value="YES" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="Five" id="Five" value="YES" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="Six" id="Six" value="YES" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Rating" id="Rating" value="" class="inputtext5" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Shared, #One, #Two, #Three, #Four').change(function() {
            $("#Rating").val(( ( $('#Shared').is(':checked') && $('#One').is(':checked') && $('#Two').is(':checked')) | ($('#Three').is(':checked') | $('#Four').is(':checked')) ) ? "M" : "L");
        });             
        </script>

  </form>              
 </tr>
</table>      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the CSS of your input element based on its value:

```
if( $("#Rating").val() == 'M' ) 
    $("#Rating").css({'color':'red', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
else 
    $("#Rating").css('color','black');
```

This will make the text red and bold if the value is `'M'` and otherwise will make the color black. You can also set `font-weight: normal` on the `else` if you want it to not be bold for that `'L'` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the colors or styles of the HTML elements after you validate something, Jquery allows to the community change them with a property named .css(). The .css() method is a convenient way to get a computed style property from the first matched element, especially in light of the different ways browsers access most of those properties.

Example:

```
<!--HTML CODE-->
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Click on me for change my backgroundcolor">

<!--Jquery code-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function({
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('#clickme').css({
        'background-color':'#000',
        'color':'#fff'
        });
        $('#clickme').attr('value','My background color is changed');
    });
});
</script>
```

If you want to know more about that, see this reference: http://api.jquery.com/css/